# usage of see vs look

Tags: word-choice, sense-verbs, see-look

My fan is convenient to carry around. ***See*** it can be closed when not in use. OR ***look*** it can be closed when not in use.

Which is correct?

Comment: ...this question changed completely while I was answering it...

Answer (score 2):

The term *see* is usually used to mean a more **passive action** as something that can be accomplished automatically or even subconsciously:

> I can see a mountain in the distance.

...while *look* is used for a more intentional and **active effort**:

> I am looking for my car keys.

When used as an exclamation, these subtleties are less pronounced but still present:

> See? There's a hare over there.

Suggests that the person has already passively seen the target in question and is therefore posed as a question, while:

> Look!  There's a hare over there.

...is requesting an active action, and therefore is formulated as a command.

Comment: sorry Southpaw!  I just saw your comment above!  I hate when that happens! lol!

Comment: @KristinaLopez No problem.  I think my answer is at least halfway reasonable still, also.

Comment: *See* is also more poetic than *Look*. An archaism like "Lo!" or "Behold!" is better modernised as "See!". Eric Crozier used this in the libretto for Britten's *Saint Nicolas:* "See! See! Three boys spring back to life..." which certainly doesn't have exactly the same meaning as "Look! Look! Three boys spring back to life."

Answer (score 1):

Either can be used, but in this way:

> **"See? It can be closed when not in use."**

OR

> **"Look! It can be closed when not in use."**